# Python Why does the fucntion return None instead of False

Tags: python

```
def func(l1, l2):
result = False
for x in l1:
    for y in l2:
        if x == y:
            result = True
            return result
```

print(func([1,2,3,4,5], [5,6,7,8,9])) >> True

print(func([1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9])) >> None

Why does the function return None in the second case? It should return 'result' which is True or False.

Comment: You need to return `result` after your loop.

Answer (score 2):

The control statement doesn't reach

```
    result = True
    return result
```

So the function has nothing to return, so it returns None.

This will return either True or False

```
def func(l1, l2):
    result = False
    for x in l1:
        for y in l2:
            if x == y:
                result = True
    return result
```

Comment: Can you please explain more clearly why this is the case? I see that the function returns result which in the case there is no equal items should stay False and returned as such.

Comment: Look at it this way: What happens after the loop has ended? Is anything returned after the loop is complete if none of the elements are found equal? Simply No. The function returns empty. If you had said return result even after the loop has ended, then it would return false.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest a much cleaner (and faster) solution? One of Python's strengths is list comprehension.

```
def func(l1, l2):
    return any([x==y for x in l1 for y in l2])

print(func([1,2,3,4,5], [5,6,7,8,9]))
print(func([1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9]))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Completely agree that your solution is much more "pythonic" but forgetting to place code outside of nested loops is common and instructive for someone getting started.

Answer (score 1):

As your function is currently written, it only works when there is a pairwise match between at least one of the elements of l1 and l2 - it would correctly set result from False to True, then return the result. However, if none of the elements in l1 and l2 are pairwise equal, the return statement is never reached because your function will exit the loop and then terminate the function - without returning anything.

Therefore, the return statement needs to be outside of the loop. Otherwise, your function won't return anything if none of the elements in the lists are equal.

```
def func(l1, l2):
    result = False
    for x in l1:
        for y in l2:
            if x == y:
                result = True
    return result
```

Comment: but the function returns result which is False in the case there is no equal elements

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? I ran your test cases and got: print(func([1,2,3,4,5], [5,6,7,8,9])) >> True; print(func([1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9])) >> False

Comment: actually I wnated to understand why this is happening. I have at least 2 other workable solutions but it is not what I need. I need to undersatnd the code

Answer (score 0):

So let's walk through what happens here. You check each element of `l1` and `l2` and if any of them are equal you return something. For now, just leave it as something. Which means in this piece of code-

```py
if x == y:
    result = True
    return result
```

You only enter do `result = True` and `return result` statement if `x == y`. If there is no scenario where `x == y` occurs as it happens in the second example you mentioned. There is a variable called `result = False` but there is no `return` statement triggered. Which means it does not return anything. So, you get a `None`.

### Right way to do this

You can make this edit in your code to make it work like you asked for-

```py
def func(l1, l2):
    result = False
    for x in l1:
        for y in l2:
            if x == y:
                result = True
                return result
    return result
```

What this does is instead of returning the `None` if the inner return statement is not triggered it returns `result` which would be `False`.